# How to display three dot in list of span inside flex container with width using css?

Tags: html, css

How to add three dots when has no space left according the container?

The chips are must display in one row (display:flex). and I want what is not fit into the container width to display `...`.

```css
section { width: 100px; display:flex;overflow:hidden;column-gap:5px;}
.chip { background: blue;color:#fff; }
```

```html
<section>
   <span class="chip">chip</span>
   <span class="chip">chip</span>
   <span class="chip">chip</span>
   <span class="chip">chip</span>
   <span class="chip">chip</span>
   <span class="chip">chip</span>
   <span class="chip">chip</span>
   <span class="chip">chip</span>
 </section>
```

I try to add, but it change the width of the `.chip` and I don't want that.

```
.chip {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

What else can I do?

Answer (score 0):

```css
    section {
      text-overflow: ellipsis;
      overflow: hidden;
      width: 100px;
      height: 1.2em;
      white-space: nowrap;
      color: #fff;
      background-color: black;
    }

    .chip {
      background: blue;
      color: #fff;
    }
```

```html
  <section>
    <span class="chip">chip</span>
    <span class="chip">chip</span>
    <span class="chip">chip</span>
    <span class="chip">chip</span>
    <span class="chip">chip</span>
    <span class="chip">chip</span>
    <span class="chip">chip</span>
    <span class="chip">chip</span>
  </section>
```

Comment: this is what I did: `section { width: 100px;`

Comment: I have edited the answer to reflect your exact use case.

Comment: thankyou, but the last chip blue is remains..

Answer (score 0):

You should move `white-space: nowrap` and `text-overflow: ellipsis` to `section`. Also remove `display: flex` from `section`:

```css
section {
  width: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}

.chip {
  background: blue;
  color: #fff;
}
```

```html
<section>
  <span class="chip">chip</span>
  <span class="chip">chip</span>
  <span class="chip">chip</span>
  <span class="chip">chip</span>
  <span class="chip">chip</span>
  <span class="chip">chip</span>
  <span class="chip">chip</span>
  <span class="chip">chip</span>
</section>
```

Comment: but the last chip blue is remains..

Comment: @JonSud You want how be it?